# How do you save compare options in Visual Studio 2010 > SQL 2012 Database Project

Tags: sql, compare, schema, project

Been using the new SQL 2012 Data Tools > SQL Server Database Project in VS 2010. Every time we do a schema compare we have to set the options for the current compare. This does not seem to be tied back to the global compare options you can set in Tools > Options. Does anybody know where to set the 'new' global compare options.

NOTE: This is the *new* SQL 2012 compare from Data Tools, and not the *old* 2005/2008 compare that comes standard with Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible without saving the schema compare itself i.e. it cannot be set on a global/template level. I usually just open the compare options manually and uncheck 'Block on possible data loss' and 'Ignore filegroup placement'.